# No matter how i write the url in ajax the response is always success

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I have this ajax request, but its not doing what i wanted it to do, it was suposed to be a GET that returned some data but no matter how i set up the URL it always gives success response even though it was not a success,

```
 var id = 5;
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        URL: "'../this is totaly wrong/" + id + "'",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log("success");
            window.location.replace("/formex");

 }
 })
```

The correct route should be "readForm/:id", but i write it like that and it give success anyway and redirects to the "/formex" page, the url i wrote here doesn't even exist it's just to prove that it gives success even though it shouldn't

Comment: Can you show how your server routes are setup?

Comment: What's the response that comes back from the server?  Sometimes an "error" is returned with a success error code but as a page with a friendly error message.  It all depends on what the server actually returns.

Comment: global.app.get('/readForm/:id', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    global.modelRespForm.readForm(function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            // error handling code goes here
            console.log("ERROR : ", err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(id);
            res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');
        }
    });
})

Answer (score 1):

Your server is doing a Console.log on error. Your server should set the HTTP Status to an error and return accordingly. In this case your Server is sending back a '200' which is the definition of a successful call.
What you could do is:

1. Return 200, but add to the returning body (maybe JSON) a field indicating an error. Then on your front end `success` handler read that field and decide if it's a valid request.
2. Return error code, such as 500, and then on your front end catch an `error` and handle.

Please make sure you understand HTTP status codes.